# Collaboration Groups not showing in the Community in Salesforce

Tags: community, chatter, feeditem

I created a group with in salesforce which is a public group. I am able to see that group within salesforce but that group is not visible in community. Can someone tell me why it’s happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Collaboration Group](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_collaborationgroup.htm) object includes the `NetworkId` field, which determines the group's availability within a specific community. This field remains empty if you create a group outside the community. To make the group visible, you need to either create it from within the community or fill the `NetworkId` field using apex code.